MSXML: Loading xml from a url non-asynchronously causes E_ACCESSDENIED
Trying to load xml from a url using msxml:
Setting .async to false (default is true) causes E_ACCESSDENIED error trying to .load from a url
var
    doc: DOMDocument60;
begin
    doc := CoDOMDocument60.Create;
    doc.async := False;  // Default is True
    doc.load('https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.xml');

Why would it cause an E_ACCESSDENIED exception?
Workaround
The workaround is easy:
var
    http: IServerXMLHTTPRequest;
    doc: DOMDocument60;
begin
    http := CoServerXMLHTTP60.Create;
    http.open('GET', 'https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.xml',
            False, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
    http.send(EmptyParam);

    doc := http.ResponseXML as DOMDocument60;

Of course i'm not asking about a workaround. I'm asking why a workaround is needed in the first place.
Interestingly, while IServerXMLHTTPRequest works, and only supports synchronous loading, asking the DOMDocument60 to use ServerHTTPRequest synchronously does not work:
var
    doc: DOMDocument60;
begin
    doc := CoDOMDocument60.Create;
    doc.async := False;            // Default is True. Must be false if we use ServerHTTPRequest
    doc.setProperty('ServerHTTPRequest', True);
    doc.load('https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.xml'); E_ACCESSDENIED

It's strange that:

using ServerHTTPRequest works
but having DOMDocument use ServerHTTPRequest fails

Which is my question: Why does it fail?
It's not using Wininet:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7032086/12597

And even if it was using WinInet, the Internet Explorer option:

Internet Options → Advanced → Security
☐ Do not save encrypted pages to disk

is unchecked.
So what's the problem?

Have you, by chance, called CoInitializeSecurity() on the thread that is running this code?

@RemyLebeau I have not called CoInitializeSecurity(). Unless Delphi calls it (like it call CoInitialize), it is uncalled. Should be it called? Is there a virtue in calling it? It seems like it is for cross-apartment/cross-process/cross-machine RPC calls; which isn't the case here.

It's a known Won't Fix bug in XMLHTTPRequest; which is based off WinINET.
The solution is to use ServerXMLHttpRequest; which is based off WinHTTP.
Which is why WinHTTP was originally created, to fix the bugs in WinInet.
